# Subwords of the infinite Fibonacci word

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, combinatorics-on-words

Let $W = 01001010010010 \ldots$ be the infinite Fibonacci word, [A003849](https://oeis.org/A003849) in the OEIS.  Let $B(m)$ be the set of $m+1$ subwords of $W$ that have length $m$, and for each such subword $u$, let $p(u)$ be the sequence of positions in $W$ where $u$ begins. Then $p(u)$ is a composite of the famous Wythoff sequences $A=$[A000201](https://oeis.org/A000201) and $B=$[A001950](https://oeis.org/A001950). Can someone figure out (or cite a reference) exactly which composites represent the subwords in $B(m)$?

Here's how it looks for $m=4$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\text{subword, } u & \text{positions, } p(u) & \text{composite} & \text{OEIS} \\
0100 & 1,6,9,14,\ldots & AAA & A134859 \\
1001 & 2,7,10,15,\ldots & BA & A035336 \\
0010 & 3,8,11,16,\ldots & AB & A003623 \\
0101 & 4,12,17,25,\ldots & AAB & A134860 \\
1010 & 5,13,18,26,\ldots & BB & A101864
\end{array}

(Links: [A134859](https://oeis.org/A134859), [A035336](https://oeis.org/A035336), [A003623](https://oeis.org/A003623), [A134860](https://oeis.org/A134860), [A101864](https://oeis.org/A101864))

(Note that for every $m$, the difference sequence of every $p(u)$ consists of Fibonacci numbers.)

Following Sam Hopkins's note, here's a definition.  Start with $0$ and apply the substitutions $0 \rightarrow 01$ and $1 \rightarrow 0$ repeatedly, like this:
$$0,01,010,01001,01001010,0100101001001,\ldots.$$
The limiting word is [A003849](https://oeis.org/A003849), one of *several* called the infinite Fibonacci word, but this one is regarded as the standard form, according to the Crossrefs section of [A014675](https://oeis.org/A014675).

Writing those words as $w_0,w_1,w_2,\ldots$, respectively, note that $w_n$ is, for $n \geq 2$, the concatenation indicated by $w_n=w_{n-1}w_{n-2}$, so that the length of $w_n$ is a Fibonacci number.

Some more background: suppose that $w$ is a word in $B(m)$. Then at least one of the words $w0$ and $w1$ must be in $B(m+1)$.  However, there is only one $w$ in $B(m)$ such that both $w0$ and $w1$ are in $B(m+1)$. Such a "splitter" turns out to be simply a reversal of an initial word of $W$, so that the first few splitters are $,0,10,010,0010,10010,\ldots$. The corresponding Wythoff composites are
$$A,B,AA,AB,BA,AAA,BB,AAB,ABA,BAA,AAAA,ABB,\ldots$$
So, if someone can tell specifically how to generate this sequence, the problem will be solved.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you defined the Fibonacci word (rather than just cite an OEIS entry).

Comment: The word you obtain over $\{A, B\}$ is determined by the choices you had to make to get that particular subword. When you do have a choice while adding a new letter to the right, $A$ stands for the choice that occurs first, and $B$ for the other one. Example: $00100\mapsto ABB$ since in the Fibonacci word $0$ occurs before $1$, $00$ after $01$, and $00100$ after $00101$. (This is mostly guessing, I'll let someone else prove it – or disprove it if I'm wrong.)

Comment: It would be nice (and good practice) if you replace each oeis reference by the corresponding hyperlink.

Comment: Since I don't believe you get automatic notifications of edits to answers, this is a manual notification that I've heavily overhauled my answer, elevating it from conjecture to theorem conditional on statements made in the question.

Answer (score 3):

> Such a "splitter" turns out to be simply a reversal of an initial word of $W$, so that the first few splitters are $,0,10,010,0010,10010,\ldots$. The corresponding Wythoff composites are
> $$A,B,AA,AB,BA,AAA,BB,AAB,ABA,BAA,AAAA,ABB,\ldots$$
> So, if someone can tell specifically how to generate this sequence, the problem will be solved.

I construct some parallel families of finite sequences in "generations", where the full sequence is obtained by concatenating all of the generations in order.

Let $W$ denote the infinite Fibonacci word.

Let $P_0 = [w_0]$, $P_1 = [w_1, w_1 w_0]$, $P_{k+2} = w_{k+2} P_k + w_{k+2} P_{k+1}$. It's easy to show by induction that the lengths of the words in $P = P_0 + P_1 + P_2 + \cdots$ are $1, 2, 3, \ldots$ and that the words themselves are all prefixes of $W$. (A useful lemma to show the latter is that $w_n w_{n-1} \cdots w_0$ is a prefix of $w_{n+2}$).

Let $r_k = \textrm{reverse}(w_k)$; equivalently $r_0 = 0$, $r_1 = 10$, $r_{k+2} = r_k r_{k+1}$. (Note that the first symbol of $r_i$ is $i \bmod 2$). Then the family $R_k$ is defined inductively as $R_0 = [r_0]$, $R_1 = [r_1, r_0 r_1]$, $R_{k+2} = R_k r_{k+2} + R_{k+1} r_{k+2}$. By construction, the $i$th word in $R_k$ is the reverse of the $i$th word in $P_k$, and therefore $R = R_0 + R_1 + R_2 + \cdots$ is the sequence of the (non-empty) splitters.

A point of interest is that the last word in $R_k$ is $r_0 r_1 \cdots r_k$, and this is a prefix of $W$ (see e.g. proposition 17 of *[Factorizations of the Fibonacci Infinite Word](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL18/Fici/fici5.pdf)*, Fici, J. Int. Seq. article 15.9.3). But it's also the reverse of a prefix, and therefore is a palindrome. Then we can work backwards along the generation and say that the $i$th *last* word in $R_k$ can be found at position $i$ in $W$.

The main sequence is $G_0 = [A]$, $G_1 = [B, AA]$, $G_{k+2} = G_k B + G_{k+1} A$. Clearly every (non-empty) Wythoff composite occurs exactly once in the sequence $G = G_0 + G_1 + G_2 + \cdots$. It will be useful to note that if $A$ has weight $1$ and $B$ has weight $2$ then every composite in $G_k$ has weight $k+1$. (In fact, $G_k$ contains precisely the composites of weight $k+1$ in lexicographic order of their reversals, but we won't use this).

Assuming the claim made in the question that compositions of $A$ and $B$ exactly index the splitters (which I don't know how to prove), we can show that the $i$th element of $G_k$ exactly indexes the $i$th element of $R_k$, so that $G$ is the desired sequence.

Observe that since $A$ and $B$ partition the domain of a Wythoff composite $S$, $SA$ and $SB$ partition its range. If the longest word indexed by $S$ is the splitter $s \in R_k$, then the construction of the generations of $R$ tells us that $sr_{k+1}$ and $sr_{k+2}$ are both splitters whose common prefix is precisely $s$.

Take the inductive hypothesis:

> The elements of $G_k$ exactly index the corresponding elements of $R_k$ for every $0 \le k \le n$.

This can be checked for $n = 1$. Suppose it holds for a given $n \ge 1$. Then for any given splitter $s \in R_{n-1}$ with corresponding composite $S \in G_{n-1}$, the splitter $sr_n$ is indexed by $SA$, and the splitter $sr_{n+1}$ must therefore be indexed by $SBT$ for some $T$. But $T$ must be empty as otherwise there is no splitter indexed by $SB$, contradicting our assumption.

Now, for the $i$th last $s' \in R_n$ with corresponding composite $S' \in G_n$ we note that $s'r_{n+1} \in R_{n+1}$ and occurs at position $i$ in $W$. Our inductive hypothesis suffices to show that $s'$ does not occur at any position $j < i$ in $W$, since otherwise it would be indexed by multiple composites in $R_n$, requiring one to be a prefix of another, which is incompatible with the observation about their weights. Therefore $i$ is the first occurrence of both $s'$ and $s'r_{n+1}$, and $s'r_{n+1}$ must be indexed by $S'A^m$ for some $m > 0$. But in fact $m = 1$ since otherwise there is no splitter indexed by $S'A$, contradicting our assumption.

---

As a by-product, we obtain an effective algorithm to determine the composite which corresponds to any subword of $W$ without explicitly calculating anything more than Fibonacci numbers.

Let $s$ be the subword of interest, and initialise $i = 0$. While $s$ is non-empty, if its first symbol is $i \bmod 2$ then emit $A$, delete (up to) $f_{i+2}$ symbols from the start of $s$, and increment $i$; otherwise emit $B$, delete (up to) $f_{i+3}$ symbols from the start of $s$, and increment $i$ twice.

---

And as a side-note, I observe that [A341258](https://oeis.org/A341258) describes a sequence of words beginning $0$, $1$, $00$, $01$, $10$, $000$, $11$, $001$, $010$, $100$, $000$, $011$, $101$, $0001$, $110$, $0010$, $0100$, $1000$, $00000$, $111$ which appears to correspond to $G$ under the substitution $0 \to A, 1 \to B$ and was submitted by Clark Kimberling in March. I assume that this is no coincidence and that you have already solved the problem by a different route.